# Calculate the sum of all odd number from 1 to 10 with for loop in MIPS

Tags: for-loop, mips

I'm writing an MIPS program using for-loop to calculate the sum of all odd number from 1 to 10.  It should be 25, yet I got 48.  I don't know where is the error.  Here's my code:

```
################# Pseudocode ##################### 
 i = 1
 n = 10
 sum = 0
   for(i=1; i<=10; i+=2) {
       sum += i;
   }
  printf("The sum of all odd number from 1 to 10 is: %d", sum);
  return 0;

################# Data segment ##################### 
        .data
msg:    .asciiz     "\ncurrent tally: \n"

################# Code segment ##################### 
    .text
    .globl  main

main:
    li      $t0, 1      # temp counter, starts at 1 
    li      $t1, 0      # set to zero, to store sum

add_loop:
    bgt    $t0, 11, end_loop    # break out of loop if counter > 11
    addi    $t0, $t0, 2          # add 2 in $t0 to skip even num
    add     $t1, $t1, $t0        # sum += i

    li      $v0, 4
    la      $a0, msg
    syscall                      # print out user-friendly msg

    li      $v0, 1
    move    $a0, $t1
    syscall                      # print out result from loop

    j       add_loop

end_loop:
    li      $v0, 10              # terminate program run and
    syscall                      # exit
```

The output:
    current tally: 
    3
    current tally: 
    8
    current tally: 
    15
    current tally: 
    24
    current tally: 
    35
    current tally: 
    48
    -- program is finished running --

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You start your `t0` var with 1 and then you add 2 before `add     $t1, $t1, $t0`, hence the first value to be summed to `t1` is 3 and you are missing 1.

Then also since the break condition is `>11`, 11 is also summed to `t1`.
Finally, you are adding +13 somewhere else as well (maybe it makes a last iteration before breaking the loop?), so -1+11+13 gives you the 23 of difference between 25 and 48.

So probably would be better to do

```
add_loop:
    bgt    $t0, 9, end_loop    # break out of loop if counter > 9 (so 9 is counted as well!)
    add     $t1, $t1, $t0        # sum += i
    addi    $t0, $t0, 2          # add 2 in $t0 to skip even num
```

Since you already start with `t0=1`

Comment: hi where is the 7 coming from?  the reason i put bgt is because it's the opposite of i <=10, so if i > 11, break out of the loop. the 7 does count to 16,  and the output is 1, 4,  9, 16 ... so it's realy close thanks.  I put bgt $t0, 9, end_loop because that's 5 cycles (since we skip by 2).  I hope there is a better way to write this to make it cleaner. thanks.